# How to fix navbar and logo/title of the webpage at top using css/flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need to help with how to fix the navbar and logo of the webpage and also how I can able to provide spacing between navbar instead of margin using flexbox.

Please advise every suggestion will be welcome.

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

#logo {
  margin-left: 2em;
}

nav {}

ul {
  display: flex;
}

li {
  margin-right: 2.5em;
  list-style-type: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1 id="logo">
    <a src="#">Portfolio</a>
  </h1>

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a src="#">Work</a></li>
      <li><a src="#">Quote</a></li>
      <li><a src="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</header>
```

Comment: Please provide more information, we can't guess what's going on. Show your HTML structure, some screenshots or references.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want a thing like this?

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 12vh;
  background-color: red;
}

#logo {
  margin-left: 2em;
  height: 100%;
  width: 7%;
}

#logo img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

nav {
  width: 40%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  nav {
    width: 60%;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="logo"><img src="https://s4.uupload.ir/files/7560b48482bfae5c-02b97ffc647f-3822363654_tji3.jpg"></div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">work</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">qoate</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Hi Arman, I like your code but can you advise what I am doing wrong so that in future I can avoid these type of mistakes.

Comment: @LazyGyan Of course you did not show your HTML. So not to be explained accurately. although I used `flex` for `ul` instead of a `margin` for any `li`. I suggest showing your HTML in your question.